# Как сделать алиасы для роутинга в next.js?

Tags: reactjs, nextjs

Я только изучаю next.js и хочу понять один момент. Например, я буду делать сайт на 2х языках: русском и английском. Хочу что бы на русском ссылка была /ru/novosti, а на английском /en/news. При этом не создавая 2 папки

Comment: `i13n` https://nextjs.org/docs - вверху слева поиск

Answer (score 0):

Простой ответ - никак.

В nextjs роутинг основан на файловой системе, при локализации

https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#locale-strategies

у тебя должна быть папка novosti а также папка news

Более сложный ответ - ты можешь сделать редирект с одного роута на другой:
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects

Также ты можешь сделать чуть более длинную ссылку вида:
./glob/[slug.js]
и дальше принимать в один файл ссылки вида
/ru/glob/novosti
/en/glob/news

В любом случае если тебе нужен Next - то лучше пользоваться его роутингом, основанным на файловой системе